# Is completion block syntax for MFMailComposeViewController mailComposeDelegate possible?

Tags: objective-c, ios, objective-c-blocks, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I would like to use the [MFMailComposeViewController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMailComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html) `mailComposeDelegate`property with completion block syntax, but not sure if that is possible.  Something similar to how the [TWTweetComposeViewController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Twitter/Reference/TWTweetSheetViewControllerClassRef/Reference/Reference.html) `completionHandler` property works:

```
TWTweetComposeViewController __weak *twee = tweeter;
tweeter.completionHandler = ^(TWTweetComposeViewControllerResult result) {
    // code here
};
```

The code I have creates the MFMailComposeViewController, but then has to save a reference my `viewController` parameter, since this "share via email" functionality is not in a `UIViewcontroller`, but a custom `MYSharing` class.

```
MFMailComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
// more code here
_viewController = viewController;
picker.mailComposeDelegate = self;
[viewController presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
```

The `mailComposeController:didFinishWithResult:error:` from [MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate_protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate) uses that `_viewController` to dismiss the modal.

```
- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError*)error {
    [_viewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Not understanding blocks very well, is there some syntax that look like this?

```
picker.mailComposeDelegate = ^(???)(??? ??? ???) {
    [viewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

I did find [MFMailComposeViewController(BlocksKit)](http://zwaldowski.github.com/BlocksKit/Documentation/Categories/MFMailComposeViewController+BlocksKit.html) (which has source on github), but even with that, the syntax conversion trips me up.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Check the delegate methods, they will probably help, though not with the blocks syntax but with callbacks at certain points.

Comment: The `_viewController = viewController` felt wrong, when I could have just referenced viewController from within a block (like with  TWTweetComposeViewController)

Comment: The delegate method passes a reference to the view controller named 'controller' no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No completion handler for MFMailComposeViewController now.

if you want to reference the view controller who presented the MFMailComposeViewController, code like below, use presentingViewController property.

```
- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError*)error {
    [controller.presentingViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just call `[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];` from the `MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate` method?

Comment: I updated the question to clarify this is not in a UIViewController, so `self` would not work.